# QML `MapGestureArea`, How can I get rotation angle on `onRotationFinished`

Tags: qt, qml

I had searched around to find examples but none I could find. in [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapgesturearea.html) doc, `onRotationFinished` would provide the `PinchEvent` but with its property that we can use them. but I can seem to find how to get the PinchObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to do something like?

```
gesture.onRotationFinished: function(event){
    console.log(event.angle, event.rotation)
}
```

Comment: Oh god, I lost a full night with this. Thank you very much. It is just a JS event. I felt so stupid after all the year working with JS lol. but QML is new for me so ... :)